# Issues with binding to $.jPlayer.event.error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, jplayer

I'm seemingly not able to bind to the `$.jPlayer.event.error` event, but I am able to bind to other event.

I'm using a Backbone view to control jPlayer, and here's the initialize function:

```
initialize: function() {
    _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'get_media_url', 'on_player_error',
              'play', 'scrub', 'move_playhead', 'on_media_progress',
              'on_player_ready', 'on_player_timeupdate', 'on_player_ended',
              'set_progress_bar',  'set_current_time', 'time_from_percent');
    // set up jplayer and bind essential events to view methods, bound to the current object
    $(this.player).jPlayer(this.player_defaults);
    $(this.player).bind($.jPlayer.event.ready, _.bind(this.on_player_ready, this));
    $(this.player).bind($.jPlayer.event.timeupdate, _.bind(this.on_player_timeupdate, this));
    $(this.player).bind($.jPlayer.event.ended, _.bind(this.on_player_ended, this));
    $(this.player).bind($.jPlayer.event.progress, _.bind(this.on_media_progress, this));
    $(this.player).bind($.jPlayer.event.error, _.bind(this.on_player_error, this));
    this.current_state = this.PAUSED;
},
on_media_progress: function(event){
    $('time#total').html($.jPlayer.convertTime(event.jPlayer.status.duration));
},

on_player_error: function(event){
    alert(event);
},
```

(cut off the rest of the methods due to brevity, but you'll see the methods are defined the same; `on_media_progress` fires without fail.  `on_player_error` however, NADA!)

`on_player_ready`, `on_player_timeupdate`, `on_player_ended` and `on_media_progress` all fire correctly.

`on_player_error`, however, never gets called.

I've got only an MP3 being passed into `setMedi`a, and I do not have Flash installed and I'm loading the page on Firefox 9.0.1, but

If I set `errorsAlert: true` in the `this.player_defaults` object, jPlayer presents it's own error dialog, but my error handler still never fires.

Comment: Could you use a jsfiddle, or can we have a link to the website you're testing on?

Comment: I can make a fiddle, but I've got to change the code to rip out the parts of our system that it's tied into.  I'll try to get this done in the AM.

Comment: Alright, did you see my answer? I have a feeling `$.jPlayer.event.error` isn't an event, but rather a class with specific error events in it.

Comment: is there any reason you're not passing your event handlers (e.g. Ready, Play, Ended etc.) via the jPlayer constructor? Does Backbone convention frown upon this?

Comment: I need to bind them to the backbone view, which doesn't seem to work when I passed them like `error: _.bind(this.on_player_error, this)` through the default_options object. The problem is believe "this" refers to the default_options object, not the parent view. I suppose I could try `_.extend(this.player_defaults, this)`, but the point is the code above *should* work, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, thanks to the jPlayer Google Group, the answer is that you need to do all your binding prior to instantiating the jPlayer object -- once it's been instantiated the error event has already fired, so you can't capture it anymore!

So you need to do this:

```
$(this.player).bind($.jPlayer.event.ready, _.bind(this.on_player_ready, this));
$(this.player).bind($.jPlayer.event.timeupdate, _.bind(this.on_player_timeupdate, this));
$(this.player).bind($.jPlayer.event.ended, _.bind(this.on_player_ended, this));
$(this.player).bind($.jPlayer.event.progress, _.bind(this.on_media_progress, this));
$(this.player).bind($.jPlayer.event.error, _.bind(this.on_player_error, this));
$(this.player).jPlayer(this.player_defaults);
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be because there are specific error events:

http://jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-event-error-codes

Comment: Those are the event types, yes. But the event is $.jPlayer.event.error. See: http://jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-events (also I tried that already too)